# HTML Form Input/Label Alignment

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table, alignment

I'm trying to create a simple registration form. In order to align everything neatly I used the table method. However the text isn't aligned in the center of the table instead being very slightly below the table. I've used similar methods before and had it work fine though.

You can see the problem here. http://www.krawczyksolutions.com/sender/register.php

The code for the table is

```
<div class="head" align="center">
    <div align="center" class="box">
        <h2>Register New Account</h2><p/>
        <form name="regform" action="javascript:checkForm();">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="fname" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lname"  class="input" size="30"/><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Company:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="comp"  class="input" size="30"/><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address Line 1:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="add1" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address Line 2:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="add2" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="city" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Postcode:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="post" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="countr" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Email:   </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="cemail" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:   </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pass" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password:   </td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="cpass" class="input" size="30" /><p/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Proceed To Payment"/><p/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS file contains the following (NOTE: Some of the elements in the CSS file arn't used on this page).

```
body
{
    background-image:url("img/backgr.jpg");
    color:#9E9E9E;
    font-family:Optima, ‘Lucida Grande’, ‘Lucida Sans Unicode’, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#header 
{
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
#footer
{
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
#leftcol
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 160px;
    width:400px;
}
#rightcol 
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
    top: 220px;
    width: 300px;
}
.inputbox
{
    background-color:black;
    color:#9E9E9E;
    font-family:Optima, ‘Lucida Grande’, ‘Lucida Sans Unicode’, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-shadow:1px;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
}
.box {width:700px;padding:15px;background-color:#fff;margin-bottom:18px;border-radius:0.6em;-moz-border-radius:0.6em;-webkit-border-radius:0.6em;}
.box {
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #111;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #111;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#111111')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#111111');
}
.head
{
    margin-top:50px;
}
.input
{
    font-size:14px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Although mason81 did solve this particular problem, anyone else coming across this should read Truth's answer regarding using just CSS rather than tables to align it. Much better and easier way to do it.

Comment: Start with a CSS reset, and then these problems either go away, or are much easier to fix. Check out the HTML5Boilerplate for a good place to start: http://html5boilerplate.com/

Comment: No tables for layout!!!!

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/ASvvQ/ no tables needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr
{
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. However why did that work. The text was sitting in the middle of the tr element and the input box was sitting in the top, so why does aligning bottom put them both into middle of tr element.

Comment: @JamesKraw this answer will solve your symptom, but not the problem. Don't use tables for layout. It **will** bite you back eventually.

Comment: I have marked this as the correct answer since it did solve the question asked, but if I could marked two answers your answer would be marked too.

Comment: I understand why you used tables @JamesKraw though Truth makes a good point. Thank you for accepting my answer and I am glad it was helpful. It looks like this was a fruitful experience for you, that is encouraging.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a table. Use the label itself to align the form.

**[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ASvvQ/)**

Comment: old habit die hard, but indeed I suppose I should migrate to using just CSS.

Comment: If one of the names is particularly long this will break the design.

Comment: @novacara oh, if the label is too long. In which case, yes. It will break, you'll have to increase the width. Note that I can easily do it with `<label for="name">` and then the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is doing that is because of the `<p/>` tags in the right-hand table cells. Take those out and if you want more space between the rows add padding styles to *all* the table cells.

EXAMPLE

```
td
{
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<td align=center>name</td>
```

Comment: -1 Use CSS for styles. Using HTML attributes to style things is bad.